# Building a Flash Builder AS project using Hudson

Tags: flash, ant, hudson, flash-builder

I have a flash builder project that has no mxml file.

I'm wondering if there's a way to build a this project using hudson or even ant.

I've previously built a FB project and used the following syntax in the build.xml

```
<target name="default">
    <mxmlc file="${SOURCE_DIRECTORY}\Test.mxml" output="${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}\Test.swf"  />
</target>
```

This time round I don't have an .mxml file in the project to use, just .as files.

Is there a similar syntax I can use to do this?

I've tried to use:

```
<target name="test">
    <fb.exportReleaseBuild project="test" />
</target>
```

Although I've found out that `fb.exportReleaseBuild` is only available on a system that has flashbuilder installed on it (This isn't possible on our build server).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: I've made some progress with mxmlc from the flex sdk, this compiles .swf directly from an .as file. I'll post an update once I'm happy with the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using mxmlc to build the .swf file from the .as file was the best way to do this.

```
e:\flex_sdk\bin\mxmlc E:\.hudson\jobs\JOB\workspace\JOB\src\Default.as
```

Or you can add the flex sdk bin directory to the path to give you mxmlc directly on the command line.